# Constant clickedElement not return the value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my function. I created const which after clicked should return me value of the clicked element. Unfortunately, it's not working....

Below JS code:

```
function tagClickHandler(event){
event.preventDefault();
const clickedElement = this;
console.log('clickedElement',clickedElement);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If element has value you should access it like this:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  const clickedValue = e.value;
  console.log('clickedValue', clickedValue);
}
```

```html
<input id="someInput" type="text" value="hello there" onClick="myFunction(this)" />
```